# to remove pseudo element :after using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have two radio buttons namely "yes" and "no".On clicking "no" button a div appears and "yes" button click that div gets hidden.My problem is that the checkmark on button doesn't get removed.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".yesRadionbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.divHide').nextAll('div').hide(500);
  });

  $(".noRadionbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.divHide').next('div').show(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesOne">
  <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">1 of 7</span></h5>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="btnContainer">YES
      <input type="radio" name="radio" class="yesRadionbtn">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 noDiv">
    <label class="btnContainer">NO
      <input type="radio" name="radio" class="noRadionbtn">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
     </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 divHide hiddenSec">
  <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">2 of 7</span></h5>
  <ul class="star">
    <li>
      Will any applicant have other health insurance in force on the policy effective date or be eligible for Medicaid?
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="btnContainer">YES
      <input type="radio" name="Secradio" class="yesRadionbtn">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 noDiv">
    <label class="btnContainer">NO
      <input type="radio" name="Secradio" class="noRadionbtn">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "My problem is that the checkmark on button doesn't get removed."?

Comment: I think you forgot to add styling.

Comment: please have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/gwf4myqn/ .

Comment: first select the two "No" buttons.Then click "yes" button you can  see that the second div gets hidden.After that click "No" button then the hidden div gets shown and the no button in that div still appears in checked state.I want to remove that.Hope you have understood the question can  you help  me sir

Answer (score 0):

You just have to uncheck radio button when you click on "yes".

So update your radio button click event "yes" to:

```
$(".yesRadionbtn").click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.divHide').nextAll('div').hide(500);
   $("input[name='Secradio']").prop("checked", false);
});
```

Updated fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/17pqha25/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(function() {
        $(".yesRadionbtn").click(function() {
            $(this).closest('.divHide').nextAll('div').hide(500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".yesRadionbtn").prop('checked', false);
            }, 500);
        });
        $(".noRadionbtn").click(function() {
            $(this).closest('.divHide').next('div').show(500);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesOne">
    <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">1 of 7</span></h5>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="btnContainer">YES
            <input type="radio" name="radio" class="yesRadionbtn">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 noDiv">
        <label class="btnContainer">NO
            <input type="radio" name="radio" class="noRadionbtn">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 divHide hiddenSec">
    <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">2 of 7</span></h5>
    <ul class="star">
        <li>
            Will any applicant have other health insurance in force on the policy effective date or be eligible for Medicaid?
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="btnContainer">YES
            <input type="radio" name="Secradio" class="yesRadionbtn">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 noDiv">
        <label class="btnContainer">NO
            <input type="radio" name="Secradio" class="noRadionbtn">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use setTimeout for better display